# Notepad++ split function regex

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm newbie for notepad++. I want to split keyword after `@` .

```
user1@yahoo.com
user34@gmail.com
john@outlook.com
```

My desired output :

```
yahoo.com
gmail.com
outlook.com
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: This is very basic: Find: `.+@` replace: `NOTHING`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `.+@`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
.+      # 1 or more any character but newline
@       # @
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]